# VS 2015 unable to start debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2015

[image]

I cannot debug my project, any one meet that issue!

Comment: you should specify starting project

Comment: The VS2015 debugger is very buggy, I've seen this message box entirely too many times.  This particular problem tends to fix itself when you restart VS, ymmv.

Answer (score 0):

Press right button on project, which you want to debug and select: **Set as StartUp Project**.